# Docker - Symfony5/Mercure : Impossible to reach mercure hub

Tags: docker, symfony, mercure

I try with no success to access to Mercure's hub through my browser at this URL :
http://locahost:3000 => ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I use Docker for my development. Here's my docker-compose.yml :

```
# docker/docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    container_name: test_db
    build:
      context: ./database
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "3309:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./database/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - ./database/data:/var/lib/mysql

  php-fpm:
    container_name: test_php
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
      - APP_SECRET=${APP_SECRET}
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql://${DATABASE_USER}:${DATABASE_PASSWORD}@database:3306/${DATABASE_NAME}?serverVersion=5.7
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www

  nginx:
    container_name: test_nginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./logs:/var/log
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    ports:
      - "8095:80"

  caddy:
    container_name: test_mercure
    image: dunglas/mercure
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeMe!'
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeMe!'
      PUBLISH_URL: '${MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL}'
      JWT_KEY: '${MERCURE_JWT_KEY}'
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS: '${MERCURE_ALLOW_ANONYMOUS}'
      CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: '${MERCURE_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS}'
      PUBLISH_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: '${MERCURE_PUBLISH_ALLOWED_ORIGINS}'
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
```

I have executed successfully :

```
docker-compose up -d
```

docker ps -a :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                                      NAMES
0e4a72fe75b2   dunglas/mercure                  "caddy run --config …"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours   443/tcp, 2019/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3000->80/tcp, :::3000->80/tcp   test_mercure
724fe920ebef   nginx                            "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:8095->80/tcp, :::8095->80/tcp                      test_nginx
9e63fddf50ef   php-fpm                          "docker-php-entrypoi…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   9000/tcp                                                   test_php
e7989b26084e   database                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:3309->3306/tcp, :::3309->3306/tcp                  test_db
```

I can reach http://localhost:8095 to access to my Symfony app but I don't know on which URL I am supposed to reach my Mercure's hub.

Thank's for your help !

Comment: Need to set `SERVER_NAME: ':80'` in the [caddy environment config](https://mercure.rocks/docs/hub/config), then should be able to access `http://localhost:3000` from the host machine if it does not conflict with ngnx. By default mercure has HTTPS enabled, which you can see by the ports in `docker ps -a` of `443/tcp` it is listening on but is not being forwarded `:::3000->80/tcp`.

Comment: Hello @WillB. and thanks for your help. I have updated my docker-compose.yaml file by adding this params as you said `SERVER_NAME: ':80'`and restart my docker but I still have the error and the command `docker ps` still display exactly the same datas in INFOS column. Maybe I miss something ?

Comment: Sounds like the caddy config did not apply the `SERVER_NAME` to port 80. Guessing it conflicts with nginx that is already listening on port 80. Try `SERVER_NAME: ':8080'` and see if `docker ps -a` lists `dunglas/mercure` with PORTS as `8080/tcp`. If so you can change your `ports: - "3000:80"` to `"3000:8080"` Otherwise you may need to use a custom config file to disable `auto_https`

Answer (score 1):

I tried for months to get symfony + nginx + mysql + phpmyadmin + mercure + docker to work both locally for development and in production (obviously). To no avail.
And, while this isn't directly answering your question. The only way I can contribute is with an "answer", as I don't have enough reputation to only comment, or I would have done that.

If you're not tied to nginx for any reason besides a means of a web server, and can replace it with caddy, I have a repo that is symfony + caddy + mysql + phpmyadmin + mercure + docker that works with SSL both locally and in production.

https://github.com/thund3rb1rd78/symfony-mercure-website-skeleton-dockerized